# Ejb - ear file intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ejb, maven-2

I am working on an existing ejb project. The git repo has the following files - ear, ejb and war in one project. Can someone please tell the steps to create an ear file using intellij.

Answer (score -1):

See the "Package the application into an EAR﻿" section of [Your first Java EE application](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-ee-application.html#ear) tutorial on JetBrains website.